# Image replacing using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have used GD library function to color my images using coordinates marked with the help of jquery editor. the problem i am facing is all these coloring in done using ajax on the same image which needs to displayed on the page. And i have replaced the image of that particular div using jquery.

```
$('.Plot_left img').attr("src" , "<?php echo $mapimage_path .'?timestamp='.strtotime(date('y-m-d h:m:d'));?>");
```

Even though i have appended timestamp in the image src iam not able to see the output at the first load. I need to refresh multiple times to see the desired output.

Is there any other solution for this.

Comment: Sounds like a cache problem or it is taking a bit of time to add the timestamp to the image.

Comment: Your timestamp is useless here, generated server side only once. Use instead as timestamp: `$.now()` client side, so try: `$('.Plot_left img').attr("src", "<?php echo $mapimage_path?>?" + $.now());`

Comment: @wolff i am clueless how do i do that?

Comment: @amit just edited previous comment, try it

Comment: jQuery part is working well: http://jsfiddle.net/ap3zT/

Comment: Yea jquery part is working fine. but the image getting replaced is kind of cut or its not colored etc.

Comment: I am aware of that fabricio. the fact is iam replacing the image using jquery. I cannot seem to understand the behaviour..

Comment: I deleted my comment because I first thought you were generating PHP on the client side which would not work because PHP is server side. But what you are probably doing is generating the JavaScript on the server side and if you follow the tip by A. Wolff then it should just work. Would you have a live demo where we could look into the problem?

Comment: Even the method mentioned by A. wolff is not working as expected.. Seems some sort of cache problem..

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes(") wont escape single quotes (') but vice versa is possible, so try this way

`$('.Plot_left img').attr("src" , '<?php echo $mapimage_path ."?timestamp=".strtotime(date("y-m-d h:m:d"));?>');`

Happy Coding :)

Comment: That doesn't really matter.

Comment: You realize that the `'`'s are in the PHP code and not in the JS code, right?